# Nestjs Microservices : Code change not reflecting in local server

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, microservices

I just started working on Nestjs microservices
Nest Version is 9.0 and the Node version is 16.0

I have created a service, and trying to make changes in code

**App.module.ts**

```
@Module({
  imports: [],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**App.controller.ts**

```
  @MessagePattern({ role: 'test', cmd: 'find_all' })
  async findAll() {
    logger.log('Hello, User!');
  }
```

**Expected Output**

Hello, User

**Actual Output**

Hello World

Answer (score 0):

After searching many things, I found that
We have to execute the below command

```
npm run build
&
npm run start
```

This resolved my issue